# element list multiply sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How would I multiply and obtain the sum of the lists in the following lists WITHOUT the use of numpy?

```
pattern = [40, 30, 20, 10]
data_list =[[-1, 2, -2, 3], [2, -2, 3, 41], [-2, 3, 41, 38], \
[3, 41, 38, 22], [41, 38, 22, 10], [38, 22, 10, -1], [22, 10, -1, 3]]
```

I want to multiply each element in the data_list by the pattern and obtain the following result.

```
expected_answer = [10, 490, 1210, 2330, 3320, 2370, 1190]
```

I've tried:

```
sum([i*j for i,j in zip(data_list, pattern)])
```

yet I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: Use numpy arrays.  lists of lists of numbers is inferior.

Answer (score 0):

You want to convolve `pattern` over `data_list`?

Iterate on `data_list` and take the sum of the products of each element in the iteratee sublist and the corresponding element in `pattern`:

```
answer = [sum(x*y for x, y in zip(lst, pattern)) for lst in data_list]
print(answer)
# [10, 490, 1210, 2330, 3320, 2370, 1190]
```

---

About your error: `i * j` performs a list multiplication/replication (not what you want), since `i` is a list and `j` is an integer, and then [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sum) tries to add the first resulting list to the default `start` parameter `0`.